# Twilio how to know who picked who's call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I just want to know if there is a way to know in twilio who picked who's call,
so i enqueue all the incoming calls and the agents calls into a queue to pick the first call.

but now i want to know the agent who picks the call and which call.

is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your agent dials into a queue, the action URL for the qeueu they connect to will fire when the call between the formerly enqueued party and the agent dialing into the queue ends. If you use the [queue member resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/member-resource) to pop the call off the queue, the action URL will fire immediately and you can direct Twilio to a new source of TwiML to handle this call.

[TwiML™ Voice: `<Enqueue>` - Action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue#attributes-action)